# Best way to calculate the distance from a target in a Grid

Tags: ios, objective-c, geometry, distance

I have a grid like this one

And I need to calculate the distance from a cell respect a target. For example cell 64 is the target and cell 99 is the current position.

A possible path for 99 must be for example cell 83, 83, 66 and 65
The path 76, 62, 63 is not correct.

I calculate the distance with this function but I think that is not well weighted

```
-(float)distanceFromTarget:(int)targetCoordinate ofCurrentObject:(int)objectCoordinate{


    int columnTarget = (targetCoordinate % 15)-1;
    int lineTarget = (targetCoordinate /15);

    int columnObject = (objectCoordinate % 15)-1;
    int lineObject = (objectCoordinate /15);

    float lato1;
    float lato2;

    if(columnObject>columnTarget) {
        lato1 = columnObject - columnTarget;
    }
    else lato1= columnTarget - columnObject;

    if(lineObject>lineTarget) {
        lato2 = lineObject - lineTarget;
    }
    else lato2= lineTarget - lineObject;


    float distance = sqrt(pow(lato1,2)+pow(lato2,2));

    return distance;



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your calculation of the column and line index is not correct (it gives a wrong result for the last cell in each row). If the grid has 15 columns and the first cell has #1 then it should be:

```
int columnTarget = (targetCoordinate - 1) % 15;
int lineTarget = (targetCoordinate - 1) / 15;

int columnObject = (objectCoordinate - 1) % 15;
int lineObject = (objectCoordinate - 1) / 15;
```

Then you can compute the horizontal and vertical difference as

```
int deltaX = abs(columnObject - columnTarget);
int deltaY = abs(lineObject - lineTarget);
```

But the final step depends on what kind of distance you want to compute.

```
float distance = sqrt(pow(deltaX,2)+pow(deltaY,2));
// Or better:
float distance = hypotf(deltaX, deltaY);
```

gives the ["Euclidean distance"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance), 
i.e. the length of a straight line between the centers of the cells.

If you want to calculate the "shortest path" where horizontal, vertical and diagonal
moves are allowed then the distance would be

```
int distance = MAX(deltaX, deltaY);
```

If only horizontal and vertical moves are allowed then the length of the shortest
path is

```
int distance = deltaX + deltaY;
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I like it! I have only some doubts, 
1)I can't understand the differences between the float distance = hypotf(deltaX, deltaY); and the int distance = MAX(deltaX, deltaY);
2) How can normalize the distance? for example max value must be between 0 and 10.
3) With my code, if for example the target is in cell 62 and the object is in cell 69. My function will put in output a better distance for the cell 61! But that move is not permitted... How can I solve this problem?

Comment: @UsiUsi: What moves are permitted?

Comment: horizontal, vertical and diagonal moves. But the object can't cross the border. For example It can't go directly from cell 69 to 61! In that position the distance must be high to discourage the object to choose that path to go in cell 61. The distance must be smaller in cell 68 so the object will choose it!

Comment: @UsiUsi: Then `distance = MAX(deltaX, deltaY)` should be exactly what you need. It is the number of moves required. For example 8 moves to go from 69 to 61, and 5 moves to go from 64 to 99.

Comment: Thank you so much! what's the difference with hypotf? to get a value between 1 and 10 can I divide to 10?

Comment: @UsiUsi: If you take a ruler and measure the distance between the centers of the cells: That's what `hypotf()` computes (in units of the cell width).

Comment: I have Update the my question with a small doubt. Can you help me please?

Comment: @UsiUsi: What exactly do you mean by "circle"? If you want to check if object and target have a distance at most "raggio" then you should compute the distance as I said in my answer and then check `if (distance > 0 && distance <= raggio) ...` .